# SSIS Failure To Connect To DB2 database on AS400 [COMException (0x80040E14)]

Tags: ssis, db2, ibm-midrange

I have setup a connection to a DB2 database on an AS400 using the .NET OLEDB Provider. When I test the connection, I get a successful message. but when I try to use the connection through a data reader, I get the below error. I've Googled this and come up with nothing helpful. Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Thanks!

```
--------------------------------------------------------------

SSIS package "DownloadData.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at DownloadData From XXxXXX, DTS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC0047062 at DownloadData From XXxXXX, AS400Conn [1]: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040E14): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E14
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManager90.AcquireConnection(Object pTransaction)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.AcquireConnections(Object transaction)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostAcquireConnections(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper90 wrapper, Object transaction)
Error: 0xC0047017 at DownloadData From XXxXXX, DTS.Pipeline: component "Blah" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0x80040E14.
Error: 0xC004700C at DownloadData From XXxXXX, DTS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at DownloadData From XXxXXX: There were errors during task validation.
Warning: 0x80019002 at DownloadData: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (5) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "DownloadData.dtsx" finished: Failure.
```